# TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webassembly, react-three-fiber

We're currently working on a project with Next.js and Three.js (react-three-fiber). After clearing the cache in the browser, the 3d model was not shown anymore.
We get some errors. Actually one warning an one error (multiple times).
The error is

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: abort(TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

We do use some environment variables but don't especially import the module "env".
The parameter ("-s ASSERTIONS=1") didn't work for us.

The other warning which appears at the start of the console output is this:

```
failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function
```

The error sometimes appears and sometimes it doesn't, we don't know why.

Thanks for anything

Edit:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
  "@next/env": "^11.1.2",
  "@react-three/drei": "^2.2.13",
  "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.6.4",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "drei": "^2.2.13",
  "framer-motion": "^4.1.8",
  "iso-3166-1": "^2.0.1",
  "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "next": "^11.0.0",
  "postcss": "^8.2.12",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-country-flag": "^2.3.0",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-fps-stats": "^0.1.3",
  "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
  "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
  "react-select": "^4.3.1",
  "react-simple-maps": "^2.3.0",
  "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
  "react-three-fiber": "^5.3.11",
  "react-time-ago": "^6.2.2",
  "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
  "swr": "^0.5.5",
  "tailwindcss": "^2.1.1",
  "three": "^0.124.0",
 "use-asset": "^1.0.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^7.24.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
  "eslint-config-next": "^11.0.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
  "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
  "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.6.0",
  "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^1.13.2",
  "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^30.0.0",
  "husky": "^6.0.0",
  "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
  "prettier": "^2.2.1"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @juliomalves No, sadly not. We don't know where this error comes from therefore we can't just make the whole project public. In the mean time we went back to a version where it worked properly and it doesn't now anymore. So we assume that some of the packages have updated or something like that. (We edited the post with a list of used packages. Hope this may help). Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in our platform, using Angular, THREE.JS, gltf+draco-compression. Haven't seen the issue before today

Comment: @baltzar We also use THREE.JS and gltf+draco-compression. May be a problem with THREE?!

Comment: @RobinAegerter I'm thinking something has changed how the draco files are decoded, could be google's draco decoder static files (we pull them from `https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/`). In our other 3D-platform we have the same setup, but it's not using webassembly to decode, instead we're using JS by: `dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: "js" });` and that works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our case we were setting the draco decoder path to:

`https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/`

by calling:

`this.dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/");`

But their recommended way is specifying the version in the URL:

`https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.3/`

They released a new version yesterday, which explains the sudden errors: https://github.com/google/draco/releases/tag/1.4.3

---

Changing to the versioned URL fixed it for us. Another fix that worked was using JS instead of Webassembly:

`this.dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: "js" });`

Comment: I had the same problem. It also appeared random. Setting setDecoderConfig fixed it for me also.